# "He is a worthless person vs He is a futile person." which sentence describes a useless person?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I want to talk about the personality of someone who is useless for any task assigned to him. Which term is more appropriate?

Comment: He is not only a worthless layabout, he is **good-for-nothing**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither “He is a worthless person” nor “He is a futile person” convey the meaning of someone who does not know how to do anything or their job. Apart from being highly offensive and insensitive; no person should be labeled *useless*, *worthless* or *futile*, we all have value. I'd suggest the following personality adjectives:

- He is (completely) [incompetent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incompetent) / inept
  He is [bone idle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bone-idle)
  He is totally [unreliable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unreliable)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. English is my second language and I try to improve it. it was useful. thanks